React Native Expo App: Location Tracking Stops While Background Running After 1 Day Using Expo Location Library
I am developing an Android mobile app using React Native with the Expo framework. The app is designed to track the user's location continuously, even when running in the background. For this, I have implemented the expo-location library to set up the GPS listener and handle background tracking.
The app works correctly for about 24 hours, but then it stops tracking the user's location. It seems like the background location tracking stops functioning entirely after a day.
I need help understanding why this happens and how I can make location tracking work continuously without interruption.
I tried using the expo-location library to implement background location tracking. I have:

Set up background and foreground location permissions.
Added listeners to track location changes.

I expected the app to track the user's location continuously without stopping, even after 24 hours about month. However, the tracking stops after running for one day.
I am looking for suggestions on:

The root cause of this issue.
How to resolve this to ensure reliable, uninterrupted background location tracking in an Expo-based app.

If expo-location is not suitable for this use case, I would appreciate recommendations for alternative libraries or approaches.
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as Location from 'expo-location';
import LottieView from 'lottie-react-native';
import { auth } from '../firebaseConfig';
import { db } from '../firebaseConfig';
import { doc, updateDoc, collection, addDoc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';

let lastFirebaseUpdate = 0; 
let isInitialLocationUpdated = false;

// Define the background task at the top-level scope
TaskManager.defineTask('background-location-task', async ({ data, error }) => {
  if (error) {
    // Check if location services are enabled
    if (error.code === 'E_LOCATION_SERVICES_DISABLED') {
      console.log("Location services turned off in background");
      await sendNotificationToAdmin("Location services turned off in background");
    } else {
      console.error("Error in background task:", error);
    }
    return;
  }

  // Check network connectivity
  try {
    const response = await fetch("https://www.google.com", { method: "HEAD" });
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Network unavailable");
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Network disconnected in background");
    await sendNotificationToAdmin("Network disconnected in background");
  }

  if (data) {
    const now = Date.now();
    const { locations } = data;

    if (locations && locations.length > 0) {
      const currentLocation = locations[0];
      console.log("Background Task - New Location:", currentLocation);

      if (isInitialLocationUpdated) {
        isInitialLocationUpdated = false; 
        return;
      }

      // Reverse geocode to get the address
      const reverseGeocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
        latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
        longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
      });

      const formattedAddress = reverseGeocode[0]?.formattedAddress || " ";
      const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
      
      if (now - lastFirebaseUpdate >= 900000) {
        lastFirebaseUpdate = now; // Update the timestamp

        const firestoreTimestamp = Timestamp.now();
        // Store the updated location in Firestore and add to Location History subcollection
        try {
          // Update main document
          await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Sales Rep', uid), {
            Latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            Longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
            Address: formattedAddress,
            Timestamp: firestoreTimestamp, // Store the current timestamp
          });

          // Add to Location History subcollection
          const locationHistoryRef = collection(db, 'Sales Rep', uid, 'Location History');
          await addDoc(locationHistoryRef, {
            Latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            Longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
            Address: formattedAddress,
            Timestamp: firestoreTimestamp,
          });

          console.log("Location updated in Firestore and Location History subcollection.");
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error updating Firestore:", error);
        }
      }
      else {
        console.log('Skipped Firebase update; less than 15 minutes elapsed');
      }

    }
  }
});

export default function SalesRepView() {
  const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState('');
  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid; // Get the current user's UID

  // Get location permission and start background tracking
  useEffect(() => {
    const getPermissionsAndLocation = async () => {
      let { status: foregroundStatus } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (foregroundStatus !== 'granted') {
        console.log("Foreground location permission not granted");
        return;
      }

      let { status: backgroundStatus } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (backgroundStatus !== 'granted') {
        console.log("Background location permission not granted");
        return;
      }

      // Start tracking the location in the background every 15 minutes
      await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('background-location-task', {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
        timeInterval: 900000, // 15 minutes in milliseconds
        distanceInterval: 0, // Receive updates as the user moves
        showsBackgroundLocationIndicator: true,
        foregroundService: {
          notificationTitle: 'Douglas & Sons (pvt) Ltd'
        },
        pausesUpdatesAutomatically: false,
      });

      let currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
      setLocation(currentLocation);
      console.log("Initial Location:", currentLocation);

      if (currentLocation) {
        let reverseGeocode = await Location.reverseGeocodeAsync({
          latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
          longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
        });

        const formattedAddress = reverseGeocode[0]?.formattedAddress || " ";
        setAddress(formattedAddress);
        console.log("Address:", formattedAddress);

        const intialTimestamp = Timestamp.now();
        // Store initial location in Firestore
        try {
          await updateDoc(doc(db, 'Sales Rep', uid), {
            Latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            Longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
            Address: formattedAddress,
            Timestamp: intialTimestamp,
          });

          // Add initial location to Location History subcollection
          const locationHistoryRef = collection(db, 'Sales Rep', uid, 'Location History');
          await addDoc(locationHistoryRef, {
            Latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            Longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude,
            Address: formattedAddress,
            Timestamp: intialTimestamp,
          });

          console.log("Initial location stored in Firestore and Location History subcollection.");
          isInitialLocationUpdated = true;

        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error storing initial data in Firestore:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    getPermissionsAndLocation();
  }, []);

  // Network disconnected monitoring
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribeNetInfo = NetInfo.addEventListener(async (state) => {
      if (!state.isConnected || !state.isInternetReachable) {
        // Optionally notify the admin
        await sendNotificationToAdmin('Network disconnected');
      }
      
    });

    return () => unsubscribeNetInfo();
  }, []);

  // Location services monitoring
  useEffect(() => {
    const checkLocationServices = async () => {
      const isLocationEnabled = await Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync();
      if (!isLocationEnabled) {
        await sendNotificationToAdmin('Location services turned off');
      }
    };

    const intervalId = setInterval(checkLocationServices, 60000); // Check every 1 minute
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  // Send notification to admin
  const sendNotificationToAdmin = async (Message) => {
    const uid = auth.currentUser.uid; // Get the current user's UID
    const salesRepRef = doc(db, 'Sales Rep', uid); // Reference to the sales rep's document

    try {
        // Fetch the sales rep's profile data
        const salesRepDoc = await getDoc(salesRepRef);

        if (salesRepDoc.exists()) {
            const { Name, Department } = salesRepDoc.data(); // Destructure Name and Department

            // Add notification to AdminNotifications collection
            const adminRef = collection(db, 'AdminNotifications');
            await addDoc(adminRef, {
                Department,
                Message,
                Name,
                Timestamp: Timestamp.now(),
            });
            
        } else {
            console.error('Sales Rep document not found');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching sales rep data:', error);
    }
};

  // Handle back button press
  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      console.log("Back button pressed");
      return true; // Prevent the default back button behavior
    };

    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);

    return () => BackHandler.removeEventListener("hardwareBackPress", backAction);
  }, []);

  
}


